# Protractor.explore() and .pause() and .enterRepl() run into a TypeError

Tags: testing, protractor

When I run a protractor test with one of those:

```
await browser.enterRepl();
await browser.pause();
await browser.debugger();
```

It runs into the following error:

```
TypeError: doneDeferred.fulfill is not a function
TypeError: doneDeferred.fulfill is not a function
    at Socket.tester.once (C:\TSO-IP\tso-ip-ui\node_modules\protractor\built\debugger.js:212:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
```

I haven't really found anyone reporting an issue like this.

```
import 'jasmine';
import {browser} from 'protractor';
import {LoginPo} from '../login.po';
import {Process_adminPo} from "./process_admin.po";

describe ('Capacity register tests', () => {

let loginPage: LoginPo;
let process_adminPo: Process_adminPo;


beforeAll (async (done:DoneFn) => {
    loginPage = new LoginPo ();
    await loginPage.openApplication ();
    await loginPage.changeLanguage ();
    done();
});

beforeEach (async (done:DoneFn) => {
    process_adminPo = new Process_adminPo ();
    done();
});

it ('Add a new nomination group', async () => {
    await process_adminPo.open ();
    await browser.explore();
    //await browser.enterRepl();
    //await browser.pause();
    //await browser.debugger();
    await browser.sleep (5000);
    await process_adminPo.clickOnNewButton ();
}
```

I expect to enter into an interactive shell (REPL) mode to deal better with locating the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to not use the `browser.repl()`, `browser.explore()`, and `browser.debugger()`. These methods require the control flow; however, since you are using `async / await` (which is awesome), that means you are not using the control flow and these methods will not work.

These are all going away because the selenium-webdriver is no longer using the control flow. Protractor used to intercept the control flow and set a magical breakpoint.

You should alternatively use `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor` See [youtu.be/6aPfHrSl0Qk?t=985](https://youtu.be/6aPfHrSl0Qk?t=985) for an example video.

Comment: thank you! What would you recommend for locating elments interactively instead? I cannot find it in the video you sent. I've been expecting to get something like Scrapy shell - you send GET request to a website, you get a webpage as a response and try in real time various xpath or css combinations on it to locate elements you need. If the combination works, you copy it from the shell to your code. Is there anything like that for Protractor?

Comment: I usually find items in the rendered DOM either by id or by css. I would avoid xpath just because it can create brittle tests. Also I think in the second example of the video we have a locator tool by text on the screen. It is a slight departure from traditional Protractor APIs but can be used together.

Comment: @cnishina Why wasn't the `--explorer` command-line option removed, then?

Comment: Explorer remained because it still could still work since webdriver promises and the control flow still was enabled by default. Removing the control flow would require major rework in this feature. I did remove it in the Protractor version that was rolled back when migrating to selenium-webdriver v4. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯